# How to check in/out files to SharePoint using httpclient in java?

Tags: java, sharepoint-2013, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I wrote a programm that can up-/download documents to sharepoint and check them in/out. It is used for data integration purposes and works quite well.

It was implemented using **SOAP**, but unfortunately the Server is configured to only be able to handle files with a size lesser than **50MB** via **SOAP**.

The server configuration is fixed, so I have to work around that.
I added some code and I am able to up/download bigger files now, but If I want to check them in via SOAP I get the same error.

Now I wonder If it is possible to checkin/out files using the httpclient.

My code so far...

```
public class HttpClient {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HttpClient.class.getName());  

    HttpClient() {
    }   

    public static void download(final String source, final File resultingFile) {
        CloseableHttpClient client = WinHttpClients.createSystem();
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(source);

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = null;      
        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(httpRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if(httpResponse.getStatusLine() != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                LOGGER.warn(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
            }else {  
                LOGGER.debug(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
                FileUtils.touch(resultingFile);
                InputStream is = entity.getContent(); 
                File outFile = new File(resultingFile.getAbsolutePath());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

                int inByte;
                while ((inByte = is.read()) != -1) {
                    fos.write(inByte);
                }
                is.close();
                fos.close(); 
                client.close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(e);
        }
    }


    public static void upload(final File source, final String destination) {    
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = WinHttpClients.createSystem();
        HttpPut httpRequest = new HttpPut(destination);
        httpRequest.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File(source.getPath())));

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
            EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());

            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine() != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                LOGGER.debug(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
                LOGGER.info("Upload of " + source.getName() + " via HTTP-Client succeeded.");
            } else if (httpResponse.getStatusLine() != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                LOGGER.debug(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
            }else {
                LOGGER.warn("Uploading " + source.getName() + " failed.");
                LOGGER.warn(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ": " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(e);
            LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage());
        }       
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @go4X, Did you get a solution? If so, can you please share? I have the same issue facing.

Comment: Sry for the late response...
I managed to bypass the problem in a dirty way. I upload a empty dummy file via SOAP and upload the content to the file via httpclient. That way I have all the Data and also the metadata in SharePoint